# How can I add spacing between a table and the paragraph immediately after it?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, libreoffice

My Body Text style has space below, but not above, and I want it to stay that way. Now, when I insert a table between two paragraphs of Body Text, I get no space between the table and the subsequent paragraph, and it seems like the only thing I can do about it is change that specific paragraph's spacing, manually adding about the same space as it has below<sup>*</sup>. There's no apparent setting for space before and after a table (like we have in LibreOffice).

What do I do?

<sub>* - I actually use a Body-Text-based style for post-table paragraphs, but that still doesn't cut it.</sub>

Comment: Hey! I posted an alternative answer. Please let me know your opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Right click the table and select table properties.
2. On the Table Tab under text wrapping select 'Around' and click
   'Positioning. . . '
3. Under 'Distance from surrounding text' click the 'Bottom' option and
   enter the value of spacing you want beneath the table.

Comment: What if the table width is less than the page width? We get text wrapping around the cell...

Comment: @TecMan, if you want to mimic an inline table then set the 'Left' and 'Right' option of distance from surrounding text both to be a large value.

Comment: Naturally any workaround is better than none and FWIM I did upvote, but this still seems like just that - a workaround, not a solution. There must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution by Adam today (May 5th 2020), but I found important problems: If the paragraph before does not include space below, it moves after the table. In last month's trial, if I added a line anywhere before a table located at the end of the page, the table jumped to the next page, which is nice, but the paragraph after the table jumped to the page before, with was not nice. I found an alternative solution that I describe below.

Create a new style named SpaceAfterTable with the following characteristics:

1. Line spacing: 0.7
2. Spacing After: 6 points (for example)

The syles used in the table must include Paragraph - Line and Page Breaks: Keep with next.

For a solution for indented paragraphs without special inter-paragraph spacing, check [How can I have spacing between tables and text when regular body paragraphs are not space separated (just indented)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1534603/how-can-i-have-spacing-between-parragaphs-without-having-to-change-styles-when-i)

Comment: What is "today's trial"?

Comment: @einpoklum It is the date when I wrote my answer and tried Adam's suggestion for the second time.

Comment: Edited your answer slightly to clarify.