# How can I have spacing between tables and text when regular body paragraphs are not space separated (just indented)?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, styles

Sometimes, I use paragraphs without special spacing between them and just indent the first line.

There does not seem to be a straightforward way to keep spaces between a table and the previous or posterior paragraph using styles (no direct formatting) unless the paragraph style includes spacing above and below.

As Lipsticks suggested, I could create a special style for the paragraphs above a table and another style for paragraphs below a table. However, if I change the order of paragraphs including one that is above or below a table, the resulting formatting will not be the desired one. I DO NOT WANT TO CHANGE STYLES WHEN I SWITCH THE ORDER OF PARAGRAPHS because I may forget and it is extra work.

How can I get inter-paragraphs spacing equal to line spacing and wider spacing between text paragraphs and tables?

Comment: I add an extra line between the paragraph above when moving another piece of text. Adding the line cancels the desire of Word to carry the Style forward.  Adjust the text and delete the extra line(s) from below (not above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Table without Title**

Create a new style named SpaceBeforeTable with the following characteristics:

1. Line spacing: 0.7
2. Spacing Before: 6 points (for example)
3. Keep with next

Create a new style named SpaceAfterTable with the following characteristics:

1. Line spacing: 0.7
2. Spacing After: 6 points (for example)

The syles used in the table must include Paragraph - Line and Page Breaks: Keep with next.

I save a table with an empty paragraph above and another below with the specified styles as a Quick Part.

**Table with Title**

For a table with title, instead of an empty paragraph before the table, I include a title paragraph with a style that incorporates the desired spacing.

I save a table with a title paragraph above and an empty space below as another Quick Part.